# data types for XML parsing

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

Is there an obvious, pythonic way when dealing with XML and deciding on what kind of data type to use?
The dictionary approach strikes me as intuitive, but I'm wondering if people who deal with XML frequently might chime in about why a dictionary is/isn't a good approach.

The shortcoming that comes to mind is the mutability of the dictionary. But if I know what data I need, then I can build dictionaries of a suitable size.

Below is a small snippet of the data that I am parsing

```
<Issuer>fotokem</Issuer>
<Creator>ClipsterDCI 4.5.0.24</Creator>
<Id>urn:uuid:6ab4b76e-0e26-4d73-8d01-6f08c96feb71</Id>
<Path>MINI-NOT-NORM-USA_ADV_F_EN-XX_51_2K_SPO_20121127_FKI_01.mxf</Path>
```

Comment: What did you already try?

Answer (score 1):

The most Pythonic way to parse XML is [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/).

Comment: You can do anything you want with your XML including creating a dictionary. `findall` uses XPath so you probably didn't pass the XPath expression you need.